# Cordova App Loggin me out if i click on the external link

Tags: javascript, cordova

Here is my code in my cordova app.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'$1\', \'_system\');">$1</a>
```

when i click the link.. the external link is opening but it is logging me out.
is it because i am using href="#' ? 
If not that, can anyone pls suggest an alterative to using #.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for it! :D

**HTML:**

```
<a onclick="openExternalURL(\'$1\', \'_system\')">$1</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function openExternalURL (yourURL){
    window.open(yourURL);
}
```

Hope it helps. Best regards!

Comment: thanks. but if i dont use href="#".. it doesnot show as a link

Comment: If it resolves the problem, you could style the <a> tag with something like this: `<a style='cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline; color: blue;' onclick="openExternalURL(\'$1\', \'_system\')">$1</a>`